# Find the number of <input> in an Div tag

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I need to find out the number `<input>` tag within a `<Div>` tag..
How it's possible.. For example the code will be like this..

```
<div><li ><a>Jayan</a><input type="checkbox" id="c21" onClick="fcheck(this);" ></li>
<li ><a href="#">Reshaba</a><input type="checkbox" id="c22" onClick="fcheck(this);" >
    <ul>
        <li ><a>crescent</a><input type="checkbox" id="c221" onClick="fcheck(this);" ></li>
        <li ><a>crescent</a><input type="checkbox" id="c222" onClick="fcheck(this);" ></li>
        <li ><a>crescent</a><input type="checkbox" id="c223" onClick="fcheck(this);" ></li>
        <li ><a>crescent</a><input type="checkbox" id="c224" onClick="fcheck(this);" ></li>
    </ul>
</li></div>
```

Please help

Thanks,

Praveen J

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why always the jquery solutions ? 
There is nothing wrong with using jquery, but including a JS library to count some elements is serious overkill.

Native javascript:

```
var inputCount = document.getElementById('divId').getElementsByTagName('input').length;
```

Comment: +1 for doing it without a framework.  I agree, for something as simple as this, a framework is overkill.

Answer (score 5):

Very easy if you can use jQuery:

```
$('#divId input').length;
```

Otherwise @Jon Grant's answer is what you need

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [getElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439(VS.85).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$("div input").length
```